# GeoServer won't start after pointing to existing external data_dir

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to upgrade GeoServer running on Tomcat (Windows).
The server is old so I am just doing an incremental 2.13.1 -> 2.14.1 upgrade.
GS start fine when using the default data dir. But when I change it to read an external data store (used by the old version) it wont start.
My experience with Tomcat is somewhat slim. But this is the first error that occur when trying to start GeoServer. Not sure if that is the relevant error? Does it give some information I don't manage to interpret?

> org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was
> scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this
> logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were
> found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
> startup time and JSP compilation time.

Comment: that's a warning not an error - most likely problem is the tomcat user doesn't have write permission to the old data directory

Comment: Ok i see. Thanks for the advice, I will look into that!

Comment: It looks like its a different issue. I took a copy of the default directory and place it in the same parent folder as the old data. I was allowed to start GS and make changes to that folder. 
I used the same web.xml from 2.13.1 and reused it for 2.14.1. Would that be a issue?

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: I was probably not clear. Geoserver does not start at all when I am pointing to the external data source. The geoserver.log itself is empty. It does start though if I move the default data dir to the external location. So it seem to be something with the old data_dir it does not like for some reason.
I modified the web.xml to match the previous one, but unfortunately that did not make any difference.

Comment: An empty log is a sure sign that Tomcat can't write to the data directory, check the log on stdout, should be in var/log/tomcat